# How this performance graph may be interpreted?

Tags: performance, mariadb, amazon-rds

#### My configuration is:

- Compute

  - AWS ECS cluster with a Django based API (Using ORM). 1vCPU and 4GB of memory per container.
- Database

  - RDS MariaDB `db.t3.medium` instance (2 vCPU, 4GB of memory)
  - `gp3` type storage (3000 IOPS provisioned, 125Mib/s base throughput)
  - Tables information:

    - `table_name_1`: `48` columns of mostly `VARCHAR(50~250)` with `49977` rows
    - `table_name_2`: `5` columns of `INT` and `DATETIME` with `49977` rows
    - `table_name_3`: `40` columns of `INT`, `VARCHAR`, `DOUBLE` with `656904` rows
    - `table_name_4`: `32` columns of `INT`, `VARCHAR`, `DOUBLE` with `727477` rows

#### Test case:

140 WEB clients are active at same time and continuously sending `GET` requests for 1 minute at two API URLs (70 clients per URL) with same query parameters per URL:

- First URL is executing only `SELECT` SQL queries. Most complicated one is:

  ```sql
  SELECT 
    `table_name_2`.`id`,
    `table_name_2`.`table_name_1_id`,
    `table_name_2`.`param_1`,
    `table_name_1`.`id`,
    `table_name_1`.`param_1`,
    `table_name_1`.`param_2`
  FROM `table_name_2`
  INNER JOIN `table_name_1` ON (
    `table_name_2`.`table_name_1_id` = `table_name_1`.`id`
  ) INNER JOIN `table_name_3` ON (
    `table_name_1`.`id` = `table_name_3`.`table_name_1_id`
  ) WHERE (
    `table_name_1`.`param_1` >= 100
    AND `table_name_1`.``param_1` <= 200
    AND `table_name_1`.`param_2` >= 100
    AND `table_name_1`.`param_2` <= 200
    AND `table_name_3`.`param_3` >= 10000
    AND `table_name_2`.`param_4` >= 10000
  ) GROUP BY `table_name_2`.`id` ORDER BY NULL
  ```

  **Query details:**

  - total number of resulted rows for `SELECT` is `234`
  - number of rows after first `JOIN` is `49977`
  - number of rows after second `JOIN` and before `GROUP_BY` is `998`
- Second URL is executing `SELECT` and `UPDATE` SQL queries. Where slow `UPDATE` is:

  ```sql
  UPDATE
    `table_name_4`
     SET `parameter_1` = CASE
       WHEN (`table_name_4`.`id` = 810982) THEN 0
       WHEN (`table_name_4`.`id` = 810983) THEN 0
       WHEN (`table_name_4`.`id` = 811066) THEN 0
       WHEN (`table_name_4`.`id` = 811075) THEN 0
       WHEN (`table_name_4`.`id` = 811076) THEN 0
       WHEN (`table_name_4`.`id` = 811077) THEN 0
       WHEN (`table_name_4`.`id` = 811078) THEN 0
       WHEN (`table_name_4`.`id` = 811079) THEN 0
       WHEN (`table_name_4`.`id` = 811103) THEN 0
       WHEN (`table_name_4`.`id` = 811159) THEN 0
       ELSE NULL
     END, `parameter_2` = CASE
       WHEN (`table_name_4`.`id` = 810982) THEN 0
       WHEN (`table_name_4`.`id` = 810983) THEN 0
       WHEN (`table_name_4`.`id` = 811066) THEN 0
       WHEN (`table_name_4`.`id` = 811075) THEN 0
       WHEN (`table_name_4`.`id` = 811076) THEN 0
       WHEN (`table_name_4`.`id` = 811077) THEN 0
       WHEN (`table_name_4`.`id` = 811078) THEN 0
       WHEN (`table_name_4`.`id` = 811079) THEN 0
       WHEN (`table_name_4`.`id` = 811103) THEN 0
       WHEN (`table_name_4`.`id` = 811159) THEN 0
       ELSE NULL
     END, `parameter_3` = CASE WHEN
  ...
  ```

  **Query details:**

  - updating `10` rows
  - Execution time is `10~15ms` when executing manually
  - total number of cases is `10`

Here is a graph of service response time:
[image]

We have `140` active clients and `12s` average response time (for `2` containers)
So real average throughput is `140 / 12 = ~12 requests/s`
In case of `6` containers average response time is about `6s`

Here are two peaks on the DB performance graph:
[image]

Two tests with different configuration:

1. `6` running ECS containers
2. `2` running ECS containers

Here is an additional graph for same time range:
[image]

#### Questions:

1. Average active sessions number is bigger for `2` containers. What is means that query per container running time is slower for `2` containers (waiting queries of `2` containers accumulates faster than `6` containers is executing new queries with less wait time). Why may it happen? DB is waiting for some kind of `Django` query complete confirmation, but `Django` response is slower in case of `2` containers (because of server load)?
2. In case of `2` containers `wait/io/table/sql/handler` wait event is extremely slow (this event is related to `UPDATE` query below), but in case of `6` containers `wait/synch/rwlock/innodb/btr_search_latch` (related to `SELECT`) needs much more time than `UPDATE` query. Why are latency reasons changing depending on application computing performance?
3. Any other suggestions what I should check based on this graph.
4. How this graph should be correctly interpreted (if it possible without knowing other system logs)?

<sub>Improving of weird SQL queries above is not an object of discussion</sub>

Comment: ask me if you need any additional information and I will try to provide it

Comment: I would lower `long_query_time` and turn on the slowlog.  With the queries in hand, things might be clearer.  This would give the timeframes.  `SHOW CREATE TABLE` would provide more info.

Comment: "140 GET request/s for 1 minute" -- Does that mean 140 benchmark-type connections pounding on the server?  140 is too high.

Comment: How big are the tables?  Need to see the `WHERE` clause on the Update.  And whether  it had a `JOIN`.

Comment: @RickJames ① → unfortunately RDS `slowquery` log is empty. Even if I set `long_query_time = 0.5`. But when I see RDS Performance monitor it shows me: `Avg latency (ms): 10606.27` for `UPDATE` query and `667.72` for `SELECT` query ② →　If I correctly understand your question, then yes. Let’s say 140 simultaneous invocations of `curl` command per second (70 per URL). Number of connections in peak is about ~1000 (3000 `max_connections` is allowed). Yes, it is high, but I don't expect fast response for current test. ⓷ → added `Tables information` and `Query details`. I hope it will help

Comment: "at two API URLs" -- This sounds like there are never more than 2 connections?  "140 simultaneous invocations of curl" -- if `curl` is synchronous, then "simultaneous" is not correct..  Maybe "consecutive"?

Comment: @RickJames `Maybe "consecutive"?` → Yep. You are right. I updated question with service test graph. Real throughput is about `10-20req/s`

Comment: Then, perhaps, `curl` and/or the network is the real cause for sluggishness.

Comment: @RickJames I don't think so. When I'm increasing number of containers average response time becomes much better (12s → 6s). Also, as you can see on second DB graph `row_lock_time` is extremely higher for second test (only `2` containers are running). We are always trying to update same rows (because API parameters are the same) so it is expected that consecutive `UPDATE`s waiting while same rows will be unlocked. But I don't understand, why `6` containers that provides better throughput and request more simultaneous `UPDATE`s than `2` containers doesn't lock rows as heavy as `2` containers